# Select query issue in SQL Server using inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server, I am trying to get the student id for which the below subject has to be assigned:

```
'English', 'Tamil', 'Maths'
```

in which I need to get the student id for which the subject 'Maths' is assigned today and subject 'English', 'Tamil' assigned on any day .

But the below query checking for all subjects assigned date is Today

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ca.student_id 
FROM 
    student st
INNER JOIN 
    student_subject ON student_subject.student_id = st.student_id 
INNER JOIN 
    subject ON subject.sub_id = student_subject.sub_id 
            AND student_subject_txt IN ('English', 'Tamil', 'Maths')  
            AND student_subject_assigned_Date = GETDATE()
GROUP BY
    ca.student_id 
HAVING
    COUNT(ca.student_id) = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select ca.student_id 
From student st
Where Exists 
   (Select * from student_subject mss
       join subject ms on ms.sub_id = mss.sub_id
    Where mss.student_id=st.student_id 
       And ms.student_subject_txt = 'Maths'
       And student_subject_assigned_Date = 
           dateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, getdate()), 0))
And Exists 
   (Select * from from student_subject etss
       join subject ets on ets.sub_id = etss.sub_id
    Where etss.student_id=st.student_id 
       And ets .student_subject_txt in ('English', 'Tamil'))
```

NOTE:  I changed GetDate() to an expression that produces a date only value instead of current date and time. GetDate() generates a date and TIme and you will not get any results.
If you are using a late version of SQL Server, you can just cast Getdate() to a Date ...

```
Select ca.student_id 
From student st
Where Exists 
   (Select * from student_subject mss
       join subject ms on ms.sub_id = mss.sub_id
    Where mss.student_id=st.student_id 
       And ms.student_subject_txt = 'Maths'
       And student_subject_assigned_Date = Cast(getdate() as Date))
And Exists 
   (Select * from from student_subject etss
       join subject ets on ets.sub_id = etss.sub_id
    Where etss.student_id=st.student_id 
       And ets .student_subject_txt in ('English', 'Tamil'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Notice you don't need `distinct`:

```
SELECT      ca.student_id 
FROM        student st
INNER JOIN  student_subject 
        ON  student_subject.student_id=st.student_id 
INNER JOIN  subject 
        ON  subject.sub_id=student_subject.sub_id 
WHERE       student_subject_txt in( 'English','Tamil', 'Maths')  
        AND (
                    (student_subject_txt = 'Maths' AND student_subject_assigned_Date = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
                OR  student_subject_txt <> 'Maths'
            )
GROUP BY    ca.student_id 
HAVING      COUNT(ca.student_id)=3;
```

**Edit**
@CharlesBretana is right, you have to compare just the date part of `getdate()`. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure what your query is trying to do but if you only want results having a count = 3 do this (I changed the group by to having):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ca.student_id FROM student st
    INNER JOIN student_subject ON  student_subject.student_id=st.student_id 
    INNER JOIN subject ON subject.sub_id=student_subject.sub_id 
    AND student_subject_txt in( 'English','Tamil', 'Maths')  and
    student_subject_assigned_Date = GETDATE()
    having ca.student_id =3;
```

Comment: Why? You can't have two `having` clauses

Comment: I only see one having statement. Just to be clear where  filters on the way in (in only examines records that match the where filter) and having filters on results.

Comment: Well, I see 2 `having` clauses :)

Comment: Copied from your code: "having ca.student_id having count(ca.student_id)=3;"

Comment: sorry I pasted incorrectly and kept 'seeing' the start of the last line. Corrected it.

Comment: Now your result is `3` or no result (if student with id = 3 didn't follow any of the subjects).